# thanks for help or thanks for the help or thanks for your help

Tags: sentence-usage

Which ones are casually acceptable as follows?

> Thanks for help.
>
> Thanks for the help.
>
> Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Thanks for the help" and "Thanks for your help" are both fine.  "Thanks for help" sounds a bit ESL to me.  If for some reason you were determined to express this in only three words, it would be "Thanks for helping".